# Is there an alternative to hook_webform_submission_render_alter()?

Tags: webforms

In Drupal 7, I was able to use `hook_webform_submission_render_alter()` to alter the rendering of webform submissions. For example, I was able to completely remove the display of specific fields depending on their answered values.

I am looking to do the same in Drupal 9, where that hook no longer exist. I tried different approaches with no luck so far.

What would be the alternative to `hook_webform_submission_render_alter()` in Webform?

Comment: hook_webform_element_access may work for you. These are entities so do read https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/group/entity_crud/9

Comment: @cilefen

While not being a direct alternative to hook_webform_submission_render_alter, your suggestion to use hook_webform_element_access in order to hide webform field when viewing submissions works great in that case!

Thank you very much, you saved me some headaches! :-)

Comment: A more precise replacement would be one of the Entity API implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your specific use case, you can use `hook_webform_element_access` to hide elements.